# Redhat Linux server totally locked down. How to bypass blocked ports?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, migration, data-migration

I'm in charge of migrating an existing server's websites to another server, but I require doing git clone and other related commands that require me to reach out into the internet and grab files. I can't even do a wget to pull in a file. The original server admins that set this up totally screwed it over with the blocked ports like :80.

I cant do anything with wget or git clone as it just hangs and can't reach any of these sites. But it can grab from redhat repos only.

And I even disabled the firewall. It's something to do on their end. Is there some sort of ssh tunneling where I can reroute the data from the server through my ssh connection in order to reach these websites?

Waiting on the server admins to do anything takes days to weeks since its an outsource IT company. I just want to get it done today.

Comment: Yes; You can do file transfers over SSH have you tried?

Comment: i can send files to the server easily via sftp. but i can't run any wget or git clone commands from the server. basically is there such a thing as a reverse ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a reverse port tunnel using ssh.  From commandline, the connection to the Redhat server would look like this:

```
ssh -R:3333:github.com:80 <server ip>
```

This creates a port on the server at 127.0.0.1:3333 - anything send to this port will be forwarded to github on port 80:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:3333/path/to/file/to/download.zip
```

You many need to update your /etc/hosts file to make sure the URL look right at the receiving end:

```
127.0.0.1 github.com
```

Comment: what about yum install command as seen on this page? http://www.techoism.com/how-to-upgrade-php-version-5-4-to-5-5-on-centosrhel/ --- i need to update php to the latest and all of the yum installs just hangs as its not able to get out to the internet to retrieve it.

Comment: @duckx Your question states that you can get stuff from the redhat repos.  Aren't you using yum for that?  How does it get security updates now?  For php, you could download the rpm with this technique, along with any dependencies, and then just install.